# How to rewrite exponential function $e^{x+c}$ into $ce^x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Tried to rewrite $e^{x+c}$ by using exponential properties $e^x.e^c=e^{x+c}$ but struggle to understand how to get into $ce^x$. Is it always the case that $c=e^c$?

**Edit:** To put in context, I solved a separable differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=y$, I get the solution is $y = e^{x+c}$. But the solution in the book is written $y=ce^x$.

Comment: Note that if $C=e^c$ then $e^{x+c}=e^c\cdot e^x=C e^x$.

Comment: $e^{x+c} = e^ce^x$. Now define $C:=e^c$.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could provide some additional context.  My *guess* is that this is popping up in an elementary calculus or differential equations class, where the solution to some DE is of the form $\mathrm{e}^{x+c}$, where $c$ is some constant of integration, which ultimately depends on some initial condition.  As others have pointed out, $\mathrm{e}^c$ is then also a constant depending on the initial condition, so it does no harm to relabel the constants and set $c = \mathrm{e}^c$ (where the $c$ on the left is different from the $c$ on the right).

Comment: If you are worried about keeping track of the constants, perhaps write $$\mathrm{e}^{x + C_1} = \mathrm{e}^{C_1} \mathrm{e}^{x} = C_2 \mathrm{e^x}, $$ where both $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constant, subject to the relation $C_2 := \mathrm{e}^{C_1}$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes, I'm trying to solve a differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=y$. By the way, can you helped me to understand in which situation that we can't relabel $c=e^c$. Thanks for your comment, I've edited my question.

Comment: @reckn there's no specific situation in that you cannot write a constant as $c$, whichever constant we are taking. So even $\log(c), e^c, \sin(c), e^{\sin(\log(c))},\dots $ can be written as only $c$ because they're **still** constants: if $c$ doesn't vary (which it can't being a constant) so does the value of every function of $c$

Answer (score 1):

It truly is :

$$e^{x+c} = e^c \cdot e^x$$

Now, if you simply manipulate the  constant $c$ to be $c := e^c$ the expression becomes the desired :

$$\boxed{e^{x+c} = ce^x}$$

Answer (score 0):

### Hint

> If $c$ is a constant then $e^c$ is still a constant.

Note that in mathematics constant are arbitrary: if a call $c$ a constant and then take $c+1$ I can still call it $c$ (note that this doesn't mean that they are the same constant, but nontheless both of them are **a** constant)

Comment: Does it mean **constant function** such $e^c, (c + 11), 3c, \sqrt{c}$, etc is also a constant?

Comment: @Inrtia Yes they are! At the end of the day if $c$ is a number, you can do anything you want whit it and it will remain a number no matter what